# Player move and shoot on its own at the start of the game(unity input system)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I start the game in the Unity editor, the player shoots and moves on its own.
Here is a video of what is happening to further explain/visualize what is happening:
[video](https://youtu.be/4-hhN_am5F4)

Here's the code of the
Pistol.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pistol : MonoBehaviour{
    private PlayerInputControls playerIC;
    [SerializeField] private Transform firepoint;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject bulletPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject objectCollector;
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    [SerializeField] private float fireRate = 0.5f;
    private float nextFire = 0f;
    private bool canShoot = false;
    public int magsize = 12;
    public int ammoOnMag= 12;
    public int ammoReserve = 80;
    public int ammoReservesSize = 80;
    public float damage, baseDamage = 50f;

    private void Awake(){
        playerIC = new PlayerInputControls();
    }
    private void Start(){
        damage = baseDamage;
        HasAmmoleft(ammoOnMag);
    }
    private void OnEnable(){
        playerIC.Enable();
        playerIC.Player.Reload.performed += _ => Reload();
        playerIC.Player.Fire.performed += _ => Fires();
        playerIC.Player.Fire.canceled += _ => ShotAnimation();
    }
    private void OnDisable(){
        playerIC.Disable();
        playerIC.Player.Reload.performed -= _ => Reload();
        playerIC.Player.Fire.performed -= _ => Fires();
        playerIC.Player.Fire.canceled -= _ => ShotAnimation();
    }
    
    public void Update(){
        HasAmmoleft(ammoOnMag);
        GameManager.Instance.ammoleft = ammoOnMag;
        GameManager.Instance.ammoReserveLeft = ammoReserve;
        GameManager.Instance.ammoReserveSize = ammoReservesSize;
    }
    public void Fires() {
        Debug.Log("Fires");
        if (canShoot == false){
            Cantshoot();
        }
        else {
            if (Time.time > nextFire) {
                nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
                Vector2 mousePos = playerIC.Player.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>();
                animator.SetBool("Fires", true);
                animator.SetBool("IsIdle", false);

                GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation, objectCollector.transform);
                bullet.SetActive(true);
               
                Small_Bullet bulletDamage = bullet.GetComponent<Small_Bullet>();
                bulletDamage.damage += this.damage;

                playerIC.Player.Fire.canceled += _ => ShotAnimation();
                ammoOnMag--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void Cantshoot() {
        if (ammoOnMag <= 0){
            animator.SetBool("NoAmmo",true);
            //no ammo audio plays here
        } else{
            animator.SetBool("NoAmmo",false);
        }
        //no ammo audio plays here
    }
    private int Reload() {
       int reloadAmount = magsize - ammoOnMag;
       reloadAmount = (ammoReserve - reloadAmount) >= 0 ?reloadAmount : ammoReserve;
       ammoOnMag += reloadAmount;
       ammoReserve -= reloadAmount;
        return ammoOnMag;
    }
    public bool HasAmmoleft(int ammoleft) {
        //checks if there's ammo left
        if (ammoleft <= 0){
            canShoot = false;
        } else {
            canShoot = true;
        }
        return canShoot;
    }

    private void ShotAnimation() {
        bool fires = animator.GetBool("Fires");
        if (fires == true) {
            animator.SetBool("Fires", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsIdle", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Movement.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D playerRb;
    [SerializeField] private Health healthScript;
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 10f;
    private PlayerInputControls playerIC;
    private float damage = 5f;
    private Vector2 movement= Vector2.zero;
    private void Awake(){
        playerIC = new PlayerInputControls();
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void OnEnable(){
        playerIC.Enable();
        playerIC.Player.Move.performed += _ => OnMove();
        playerIC.Player.Takedamage.performed += _ => OnTakedamge();
    }
    private void OnDisable(){
        playerIC.Disable();
        playerIC.Player.Move.performed -= _ => OnMove();
        playerIC.Player.Move.canceled -= _ => OnMove();
        playerIC.Player.Takedamage.performed -= _ => OnTakedamge();
    }
    
    private void Start(){
    }
    private void Update(){
        Debug.Log(movement);
    }
    private void OnTakedamge(){
        healthScript.PlayerTakeDamage(90f);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate(){
    }
    private void OnMove(){
        movement = playerIC.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        playerRb.velocity = movement * movementSpeed;
    }
}
```

at first i used FixedUpdate and the thing happened and tried using the OnMove(); but it still happens

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting your gamepad?